# How to get the columns count in a given table in SQL?

Tags: sql, dbeaver, column-count

I want to get the column count in the given table in SQL. I'm using the DBeaver to do the queries.

Comment: What do you mean with "column count"?

Comment: Columns in a Tables. 
As an example,
Imagine the Table name is Employee.
It should have Emp_ID, Emp_Name,Emp_Bday,Emp_City etc

Comment: What is your DBMS?

Comment: I'm using DBeaver.

DBeaver is a SQL client software application and a database administration tool. For relational databases, it uses the JDBC application programming interface to interact with databases via a JDBC driver. For other databases, it uses proprietary database drivers.

Comment: I was asking what your DBMS was, not your query tool. A DBMS is for example MySQL, Firebird, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Db2, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that connected to a postgres database?  Try this script see if it gives you the column count you are a looking for.  Remove the aggregate function and it'll give you a lot more system related info on that table

```
SELECT COUNT(Column_Name) AS ColumnCount
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'name of schema'
AND table_name = 'table name';
```